# campo auto_increment en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda sobre este tipo de campo, cuando se insertan exactamente al mismo tiempo a una base de datos los valores, es posible les asigne el mismo valor o que se genere un error ya que estos campos también son únicos, es decir que le genere el mismo numero a ambas entradas, o no debería haber problemas?

lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente

```
$this->TarjetaID=' ';
  $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO " . self::TABLE . " (TarjetaID,PacienteNombre,PacienteApellido,PacienteCedula,PacienteTelefono,PacienteCelular,PacienteEmail,PacienteGenero,PacFechaNacimiento,SeguroID,UsuarioID,MedicoTratante, via_creacion, PacienteEstatus, Medico_Tratante,emailWebService , RepresentanteID ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $query->execute(
    array(
      $this->TarjetaID,
      strtoupper($this->PacienteNombre),
      strtoupper($this->PacienteApellido),
      $this->PacienteCedula,
      $this->PacienteTelefono,
      $this->PacienteCelular,
      $this->PacienteEmail,
      $this->PacienteGenero,
      $this->PacFechaNacimiento,
      $this->SeguroID,
      $this->UsuarioID,
      $this->MedicoTratante,
      $this->ViaCreacion, 
      $this->PacienteEstatus, 
      $this->Medico_Tratante,
      $this->emailWebService,
      $this->RepresentanteID
    )
  );
   $ultimo =$this->db->lastInsertId();
   $tarjetaID ='900'.$ultimo;
   $pacient = new Paciente();
   $pacient->updateTarjeta($tarjetaID,$ultimo);
   $this->TarjetaID= $tarjetaID;
```

El problema que tengo es que al momento de insertar algunos registros se estan quedando por fuera, ya que el campo tarjetaID se crea como vaciá, entonces es posible que al momento de crearce el primero si se cree, pero el que le sigue no, debido al campo tarjeta es unica pero como se muestra luego de crearse se actualiza con el id, no se si seria mejor no enviar la tarjeta para que quede nula y luego si actualizarla con el numero del ID, o si esto también falla

Comment: ¿Como vas a insertar 2 al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Los valores nunca se insertar EXACTAMENTE AL MISMO TIEMPO. En una diferencia de macrosegundos, se van insertando uno por uno. Bueno quizás exagero, pero las diferencias son muy mínimas, y no se hacen un 2x1...

Comment: BTW esta pregunta no creo que este con los lineamientos de SOes y quizás sea cerrada.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, pero si hubiera el caso donde mi sistema este en linea, y dos usuarios se registraran exactamente al mismo tiempo, fallaría el auto incremental?

Comment: No hay forma que lo hagan al exacto mismo tiempo. Lo que puede pasar, es que hagas mal algun proceso, y tu mandes mal los datos, la misma id por ejemplo.

Comment: No, un identity o auto_increment justamente garantiza que no haya dos filas con el mismo id o número.

Comment: Ya entiendo, pero como podria resolver lo siguiente  que al momento de insertar algunos registros se están quedando por fuera, ya que el campo tarjetaID se crea como vaciá, entonces es posible que al momento de crearse el primero si se cree, pero el que le sigue no, debido al campo tarjeta es única pero como se muestra luego de crearse se actualiza con el id, no se si seria mejor no enviar la tarjeta para que quede nula y luego si actualizarla con el numero del ID, o si esto también falla

Comment: El campo autoincremental es único e irrepetible, si 2 o mas usuarios interactúan con un sistema, solo podrán realizar una inserción a la vez, este campo esta fuera del ámbito de las aplicaciones, lo ingresa directamente el SGBD, por ende es muy útil para no repetir registros, si lo que pretendes es usar esta unicidad para identificar una tarjeta este dato lo debes usar después de la inserción.